# How can I store custom metadata on my GridFS using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs, bson

For the last couple of days I've been trying to add some custom metadata to the files I insert in my GridFS.

The insertion is done correctly without any metadata at all, but all my attempts to add custom metadata (using BSON.encode(), json_utils, as json itself) are inserted but incorrectly, as shown below:

[image: One of the incorrect isertions]

(this is just for one of the many attempts)

and, if I try to delete it from MongoVue I get the following error:

```
Error in deleting file - Screenshot.C1.P94.74CB87859F8929FA289AAC1AF448FDE6121137C0.png
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type    'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'.
Type: System.InvalidCastException
Stack:    at MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue.get_AsBsonDocument()
at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.CacheFileInfo(BsonDocument fileInfo)
at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.Refresh()
at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.get_Exists()
at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.Delete()
```

It looks like I have to insert the metadata as BSON document but I have found no way to do so.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
file_id = grid_fs.put(file_from_disk, 
  filename="feature_arrays.npz", 
  comment="compressed numpy arrays", 
  meta="this is some meta")
```

And I think this should also work with a dict instead of a string for "meta" or whatever. You could also store all of your meta-data with keywords like:

```
file_id = grid_fs.put(file_from_disk, 
  meta1=link_to_img, 
  meta2=author,
  meta3=datetime.now())
```

As far as I know you shouldn't bother about BSON when using the python driver.